# Rest api: having trouble with root path directory

Tags: php, html, file, postman, directory-structure

I am pretty sure Im writing the directory wrong.

This is the error Im getting on Postman:

> **Warning**:  require_once(./includes/functions.php): failed
> to open stream: No such file or directory in
> **/var/www/html/includes/database.php** on line **3**
>  
>  **Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed opening required
> './includes/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
> **/var/www/html/includes/database.php** on line **3**

My file structure:

```
PHP
_api/
__index.php
_includes/
__database.php
__functions.php
```

My index.php file:

```
 <?php   

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    require_once('../includes/database.php'); 
    $db = new operations();
    $result=$db->view_record();
?>
```

The require_once in the database.php file:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once('./includes/functions.php');
?>
```

And in functions.php:

```
<?php require_once('./includes/database.php');?>
```

If somebody can help me to find what Im missing on my code I'll appreciate! :)

Comment: Using relative paths can be fun. In path names a single dot . means from the same folder. A Double dot means "up one level". So your database.php trying to find /includes/includes/functions.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative path and because `database.php` and `functions.php` are in the `includes` folder, you can just remove the `includes` part in the path.

i.e:

```
database.php
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once('functions.php');
?>
```

```
functions.php
<?php require_once('database.php');?>
```

Another way to do this is to use absolute path when your include/require (I prefer this way)

i.e:

```
database.php
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/../includes/functions.php');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sometimes sending to the correct path can be tricky!